# implement full audit trail for firebase use

Tags: firebase

How would I go about implementing a full audit trail for users interacting with a firebase database?

I would need to comply with guidelines for medical records i.e. reference identity of user, authorizations schema, action (c/r/u/d), subject of action.

Based on feedback so far options are logging from the client or setting up a service that listens for changes.

However the client can be tampered with and a service listening for changes would miss the reads.

Ideally I would like to use the .write and .read rules because there I have the auth token payload and ruledatasnapshots. As far as I can gather you can only return a boolean and not perform any database interactions in the rules file.

Comment: You probably know this but I don't think Firebase is HIPAA compliant as of yet so be careful recording patient data. As far as an audit trail, that could be coded in your app but how you implement it would depend a bit on your platform. Can you expand your question a bit? What platform? What have you tried so far? Do you have any thoughts about how you want to review/examine the audit trail?

Comment: Possibilities feel pretty endless here. Write data to a separate path with a timestamp; set up a listener to capture child_added/changed/removde events and send them to an external system, file, sql, or database of your choice; plenty of options.

Comment: I have elaborated the question a bit

Comment: It seems that what you are after is something that happens server side to track transactions, which Firebase doesn't offer at this time. If the client can be tampered with (not sure what that means exactly) then wouldn't all of the data read or written from Firebase be at risk? You could easily track reads or any interaction by, as Kato mentions, writing them out to a separate node, or even a separate url with independent 'admin' authorization. Maybe re-thinking the data structure and securing the data so it can't be tampered with might be an option?

Comment: By tampering I mean that you could have valid credentials and view the data as you're supposed to, but block the logging of that viewing. I understand firebase's limitations now. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Note that Firebase Realtime Database now integrates with StackDriver to provide auditing. Read the blog post [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/realtime-database-monitoring-with.html).